# Remove all CKShare records

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

## Scenario

- UserA shares 5 records with UserB
- UserC shares 3 records with UserB
- UserD shares 10 records with UserB
- UserB has accepted all these shares.

## Goal

I would like to provide the ability for UserB to remove all records that have been shared with UserB.

## Questions

1. How would UserB be able to delete all the shares that UserB has accepted without having to remove one by one through `UICloudSharingController` ?
2. Does it involve querying all `CKShare` records and deleting them ? If so how would you query (what would be the record type) ?
3. Does it involve deleting all the shared record zones ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting All Shared Record zones would result in deleting all `CKShare` records

1. Fetch All Shared Record Zones
2. Delete Share RecordZone IDs. (Using `CKModifyRecordZonesOperation`)

Comment: How do I delete the shares in the zone without deleting the entire zone?